# Why ions can't stay in metal?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, solid-state-physics, conductors, ions

Let's look at the following image.

[image]

On the left side, we got metal of Zn atoms. They want to lose 2 electrons, hence from the right side, Cu2+ attracts them. Due to this, Zn becomes Zn2-. Now, the most important part is it's said Zn ion(Zn2-) can't stay in a metal, hence Zn metal from the beginning is put into water.

I wonder, if we hadn't put Zn metal in a water from the beginning, what would happen? As in, if we had the picture exactly as I showed, what wouldn't work? why is it needed to put Zn metal in the water? If Zn becomes Zn2- ion, so what?

Comment: The zinc metal is oxidized to zinc ions having +2 charge, not -2 charge. This happens at the surface of the zinc metal anode, not inside the metal. Please read about the Daniell cell in wikipedia or elsewhere. Here is the Daniell cell pictorially: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/118744/79678.

Comment: You can benefit **greatly** by getting this and working through it: K. Schmidt-Rohr, "How Batteries Store and Release Energy: Explaining Basic Electrochemistry", J. Chem. Ed., 95 (10) (2018) 1801-1810. The Zn and Cu Daniell cell is addressed in great detail. TL; DR Cohesive energy differences are the major factor in explaining the behavior of this famous galvanic cell.

Answer (score 3):

Electric current flows in circles: that's why we call these things circuits. At every point in a circuit, the net current flow must be zero: the inflow of current must balance the outflow (Kirchhoff's Current Law). In a battery with a zinc anode, the flow of negatively charged electrons from the anode into the wire is balanced by a flow of positively charged ions from the anode into the electrolyte. In your diagram, the zinc ions have no path into the electrolyte, so the circuit isn't closed.

Comment: (+1) Good answer. We get fairly frequent voltaic cell questions over at chemistry and answer them, as [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/153076/79678), but voltaic cell queries never seem to stop.

Comment: @EdV A common misconception here is that current is a flow of electrons.

Comment: Exactly! Then the salt bridge is a bridge too far for some …

Comment: True, but note that I copied the picture from https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/118744/133719 . you can see that there's no circuit there at all. So not sure how your answer relates to kirchoff or circuits

Comment: I understand why salt bridge exists, but without it, I don't get why Zn ions from Zn metal go into water(why they need water at all)

Comment: Please, OP, read the paper I referenced in my comment! The zinc ions are hydrated and this is **one** of the factors at play in what goes on at the electrode surface. The electrochemistry happens at the interface between the zinc metal anode and the aqueous solution. Zinc metal atoms are **NOT** being oxidized inside the zinc metal anode, so your question is based on a misunderstanding.

Comment: @GiorgiLagidze There most certainly is a circuit in that diagram. Where do you imagine it's broken?

Comment: @GiorgiLagidze The function of the water is that for a current of electrons, it's an insulator, while for a current of ions it's a conductor.